# How do I get value of jsx attributes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I have this code below and I want to compare if my state is equal to some jsx attribute. How can be able to get it in line?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AccessCriteriaForm = () => {
  const [active_tab_id , set_active_tab] = useState("home-tab")
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`tab `+ (active_tab_id=="/**get the value of data-tab atribute */")?"show":"" } data-tab="home-tab" >Hi there</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check the value directly? active_tab_id==="home-tab"

Comment: True, That is helpful. I think I was overthinking it, BUt anyway is it possible?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use the data attributes? Storing data about your application's state in the DOM is something I'd consider to be an antipattern in React - you can store it as props or state without putting it in the DOM, so unless you're trying to integrate a legacy library that requires it, I'd avoid it (and in cases like that there's often off-the-shelf React versions anyway)

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the attribute of the `div` by injecting react `ref`, you can find more details at react `ref` docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html